# How to load asset with same name, but placed in different folders from assetbundle?

Tags: unity-game-engine, assetbundle

I am using unity5.3.3, I would like to know how should I get the asset from an asset bundle, whose names are same but are kept in different folder. My AssetBundle Folder is set in the following manner:

```
 MyAssets -> this Folder is packed as an AssetBundle
  -ThemeOne(folder)
     - Logo.png
  -ThemerTwo(folder)
     - Logo.Png
```

When I do `AssetBundle.LoadAssetAsync("Logo")`. I end getting the logo in the first(ThemeOne) folder. So how do I access the file in the other folder?

I have just created a [sample project](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B-nYDSH78Lkpd1FzMHRtanpXbXc/view?usp=sharing) so that you can check it out. Check the Folder Assets\AssetBundleSample\SampleAssets\Theme and the script LoadAssets

Answer (score 0):

You can put the ThemeOne(folder) and ThemeTwo(folder) in Resources Folder under assets and than use something like this

```
(AudioClip)(Resources.Load ("Sounds/" + "myaudioclip", typeof(AudioClip)) as AudioClip)
```

similarly load your png giving folder name first as i have given sounds and than name of file as i have given myaudioclip . 
cast as texture or something as you want

Comment: I don't want to embed these assets with the game initially by putting them in Resource folder. Rather want to download the assetBundle at later point in time and then load the individual assets.

Comment: Have you created the asset Bundle successfully because i have read somewhere that it won't let you add assets with same name even in different folders.

Comment: Yes in the older AssetBundle API you couldn't create the assetBundle unless you used BuildPipeline.BuildAssetBundleExplicitAssetNames. But I have created the assetbundle successfully in unity5. So am wondering if am missing something trivial here.

Comment: doesn't LoadAssetAsync works like this.LoadAssetAsync (Assets/ThemeOne/Logo.png)

Answer (score 0):

As [unity official docs](http://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/DownloadingAssetBundles.html) provided

```
public string BundleURL;
   public string AssetName;
   IEnumerator Start() {
     // Download the file from the URL. It will not be saved in the Cache
     using (WWW www = new WWW(BundleURL)) {
         yield return www;
         if (www.error != null)
             throw new Exception("WWW download had an error:" + www.error);
         AssetBundle bundle = www.assetBundle;
         if (AssetName == "")
             Instantiate(bundle.mainAsset);
         else
             Instantiate(bundle.LoadAsset(AssetName));
                   // Unload the AssetBundles compressed contents to conserve memory
                   bundle.Unload(false);

     } // memory is freed from the web stream (www.Dispose() gets called implicitly)
   }
```

BundleURL will use the path where your actual assets is located. You can also use [Application.dataPath](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Application-dataPath.html) in conjunction with ur specified path string.

Comment: I have actually loaded the assetbundle. Where I am stuck is at this point `bundle.LoadAsset(AssetName)` . When I do `bundle.LoadAsset("Logo")` I only the asset from the first folder.

Comment: as i said you need to change URL for accessing the second logo. you have to change the path according to your location. simple

Comment: Both assets are in one single AssetBundle. The problem is not with loading of assetBundle, it is accessing assets inside the assetbundle once it is loaded in the memory.

Comment: so there is only single file name which you will use if it contains both assets then surely it will load it

Answer (score 0):

Seems to be a bug. Still present in Unity version 5.3.3.

See: http://answers.unity3d.com/questions/1083400/asset-bundle-cant-have-multiple-files-with-the-sam.html

Answer (score 0):

I'm not really sure if this is possible, you should read [Explicit naming of assets](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/BuildPipeline.BuildAssetBundleExplicitAssetNames.html) which is FYI obsolete as on Unity 5.6. This allows you to explicitly name assets that you are including in the bundle. Alternatively, you could try,

`bundle.LoadAsset("/Assets/ThemerTwo/Logo.png")`

But generally, this is a bad practice to have assets of the same naming in the same bundle.

Answer (score -1):

You can use the method LoadAssetAtPath() to specify the full path instead of just the asset name.

Example:

```
LoadAssetAtPath("Assets/Texture/Logo.jpg", typeof(Texture2D));
```

Documentation here: http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/AssetDatabase.LoadAssetAtPath.html

Comment: The folder is packed as an assetBundle and am using the Assetbundle API to load assets. So I load the assetBundle at runtime and load individual assets from it. So LoadAssetAtPath is not the solution.